# How to exclude module-info.java from checkstyle plugin checks?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, java-9, maven-checkstyle-plugin

After adding `module-info.java` files to my project my checkstyle plugin start failing with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check
>   (default-cli) on project email: Failed during checkstyle
>   configuration: NoViableAltException occurred during the analysis of
>   file
>   /home/xxx/IdeaProjects/blynk-server/server/notifications/email/src/main/java/module-info.java.
>   unexpected token: module -> [Help 1]

I tried

```
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="module\-info\.java$"/>
</module>
```

However, it failed with:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.17:check
>   (default-cli) on project blynk: Failed during checkstyle
>   configuration: cannot initialize module
>   BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter - Unable to instantiate
>   'BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter' class, it is also not possible to
>   instantiate it as
>   com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.annotation.BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter

What is the correct way for skipping `module-info.java` files during checkstyle for maven-checkstyle-plugin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not sure why the Checkstyle filter is not working (this [reported bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/eclipse-cs/bugs/415/) seems very similar to yours and it was fixed in version 7.3.0, so maybe you need to update Checkstyle).

Anyway the Maven `excludes` element is also supposed to do this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>**/module-info.java</excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More in the [plugin goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html) documentation.

Comment: Well ideally the checkstyle plugin should be expected to not throw an exception for `module-info.java`, isn't it?

Comment: @nullpointer Yes. But I don't know if they support it already. I found [this page](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filefilters.html) from their documentation which suggests it cannot read the file.

Comment: Ya seems like some work is in progress in that direction. I'd tried [detailing it as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46496192/1746118).

Answer (score 9):

[`BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filefilters.html#BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter) was added in Checkstyle 7.2.

But the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` version 3.0.0 (which is the latest version as of 2018-04-01) uses Checkstyle 6.18 by default.

*"Checkstyle" and "Checkstyle Maven Plugin" are different things and have different release cycles.*

You may want to [upgrade the Checkstyle version](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html) as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version> <!-- Checkstyle Plugin version -->

  <!-- ... Configuration, Executions ... -->

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
      <version>8.8</version> <!-- Checkstyle version -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

After that, `BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter` as well as other newer Checkstyle features (e.g. new checks) will be recognized.

Answer (score 4):

Though this doesn't possibly qualify as an answer. Yet being too long to fit in comment, just to keep a note of the track that the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` is in:-

- The [last release](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-checkstyle-plugin%22) of the was version `2.17` on 15-Oct-2015 which was almost 2 years back.
- The current trunk of maven-plugins points to an ongoing work within the plugin in its [`3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-checkstyle-plugin/pom.xml#L33) version which might mean we can soon expect a `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0` sometime in near future and  which would understand the `module-info.java` as a class.
- This doesn't align with the [Java+9+-+Jigsaw](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) doc that specifies the list of modules and plugins that are being upgraded to support JDK-9.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the Maven plugin. The plugin internally delegates to Checkstyle. Supporting `module-info.java` should likely be done on Checkstyle's side and not Maven (this explains your third point about the missing reference to the plugin in the upgrade wiki).

Comment: @manouti the point I tried bringing up was that checkstyle support is probably being built in with the plugin update.